# Symfony 2 : Change the Target Directory in generate:bundle

Tags: symfony, directory, bundle, target

Where is the file to change the config about the Target Directory?

When i create a bundle, it want to put it in app/cache instead of src. I'd like to configurate it to not have to change it everytime.

Sorry for my english.

Thanks for any answer.

Comment: what have your tried so far?

Comment: I encountered the same problem after upgrading to newest version of Symfony:/ Before it worked fine, now it wants to put the src inside cache folder.

Comment: i tried looking in all routing or conf files, but didn't saw any Target Directory.

Comment: Ditto, I've come across the same issue on the latest Symfony2 version. I end up having to manually set the Target path back to /folder/projectname/src.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know there is no config file for SensioGeneratorBundle.

Maybe you want to create a wrapper around the GenerateBundleCommand?

You could either create a custom Command in one of your bundles with a configuration option for the target directory and call `generate:bunlde --dir=$directory` inside YourCustomCommand::execute() or create a simple shell script.

Comment: Ok thanks, i'll try to do one but i hope that they will fix it in next MAJ